# Office Scripts - Delete filtered ranges

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

Good day! I have filtered out values I do not want from my table. I wish to delete them and move rows up. I am getting error on delete. Any advice where I go wrong?

```js
let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
table1.getColumnByName("Column172").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(["1", "2", "3"]);

let visibleTableRange = table1.getRange().getVisibleView();
let visibleTableRangeValues = visibleTableRange.getValues();

let stuff = report.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0,visibleTableRange.getRowCount(), visibleTableRange.getColumnCount());

report.getRange("stuff").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
```

It errors out on the alst line of code.

Comment: Where is `report` coming from that's being used by the `stuff` variable. Is that value defined and assigned somewhere else in the code?

Comment: My worksheet is named report.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Report")
        let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    
        table1.getColumnByName("Column172").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(["1", "2", "3"]);
        let visibleRows = table1.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getVisibleView().getRows()
        let firstVisibleRow = visibleRows[0].getRange().getRowIndex() + 1
        let lastVisibleRow = visibleRows[visibleRows.length-1].getRange().getRowIndex() + 1
        
        sh.getRange(`${firstVisibleRow}:${lastVisibleRow}`).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
    
        table1.getColumnByName("Column172").getFilter().clear()
    }
```

The code works by getting the row index of the first row in the table's visible range. And the row index of the last row in the table's visible range. With those two row numbers, you can use the `getRange()` with the worksheet to delete the row ranges.

One thing to note about this is that everything within the row range of the visible range is deleted. So if you have adjacent data next to the table that's located in the visible range, it will be deleted as well. So just an FYI.